# Multiple row SQL Where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

This is probably a simple SQL statement, but it's been a while since I've done SQL and I'm having issues with it.  I have this table design:

```
 ID   PositionId    Qty     LeagueId
 1        1          1         5
 2        3          2         5
 3        8          5         2
 4        1          6         4
```

What I need to get are all the rows that have specific PositionId's and Qty's.  Something like:

```
 SELECT       ID, PositionId, LeagueId, Qty
 FROM         Lineups
 WHERE        (PositionId = 1 AND Qty = 1) AND (PositionId = 3 AND Qty = 2)
```

What I'm trying to get is LeagueId 5 returned since it has both PositionId of 1 and Qty 1 and PositionId of 3 and Qty 2.  I don't want to use an OR statement because if I change the WHERE to:

```
 WHERE (PositionId = 1 AND Qty = 1) OR (PositionId = 3 AND Qty = 1)
```

Then LeagueId of 5 will still get returned.

Comment: You want to return only a single LeagueID even if the PositionID and Qty values match more than once?

Comment: Well, it would, obviously, be multiple rows, of the same LeagueId, so I'll need to use the Distinct keyword.  This is just a subset of data, but it should also return all the LeagueId's that have have PositionId of 1 and Qty of 1 and PositionId of 3 and Qty of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Select Distinct LeagueId
   From LineUps L
   Where Exists (Select * From LineUps
                 Where LeagueId = L.LeagueId
                    And PositionId = 1 
                    And Qty = 1)
     And Exists (Select * From LineUps
                 Where LeagueId = L.LeagueId
                    And PositionId = 3 
                    And Qty = 2)
```

This more closely semantically represents your intent

Comment: This can be written a lot easier (and probably more efficiently) using:

SELECT DISTINCT LeagueId
FROM LineUps 
WHERE (positionId, Qty) IN ( (1,1), (3,2) )

Comment: Never count on what effect the syntax you use will have on performance. In most DB vendor's products, the Query Processor / optimizer has wide latitude in how it decides to implement your sql, as long as it conforms to the logical intent. For that reason, unless there is a known performance issue, I would tend to use the SQL that most closely represents the logical intent.

Answer (score 9):

A general way of performing this would be:

```
 SELECT       LeagueId
 FROM         Lineups
 WHERE        (PositionId = 1 AND Qty = 1) OR (PositionId = 3 AND Qty = 2) OR ...
 GROUP BY     LeagueId
 HAVING COUNT(*) = <number of OR'ed together clauses>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should return 5:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lineups1.leagueid
FROM lineups AS lineups1 INNER JOIN lineups AS LINEUPS2 
ON lineups1.LeagueId=lineups2.LeagueId
WHERE lineups1.PositionId=1 AND lineups2.Qty = 1 
  AND  lineups2.PositionId=3 AND lineups2.Qty = 2
```

Since you can only select single rows, you have to JOIN another table if you want to consider more than one. In this case, the table you're "self-joining" lineups, retrieving the value from one row based on conditions from another row (of course it doesn't matter whose leagueid you take because they're identical).

**Update** You can of course extend this to

```
SELECT lineups1.ID, ..., lineupts2.ID, ...
```

to retrieve whichever fields you want to retrieve.

Comment: having written this, I like both Charles' and Will's approach better ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT       DISTINCT LeagueId /*to display non-repeating record*/
FROM         Lineups
WHERE        PositionId in (1,3) AND Qty in (1,2) /*OR*/
```

The First statement will return 2 records which the League ID's are 5, but if your intention is to get the league ID's containing those positions and QTY, replace the 'AND' with 'OR' then it will return league Id 4 and 5.

Comment: If you can add some explanation to this answer, it would be even better :)

Comment: The First statement will return 2 records which the League ID's are 5, but If your intention is to get the league ID's containing those positions and QTY replace the 'AND' with 'OR' then it will return league Id 4 and 5. Hope  this will help. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
SELECT       ID, PositionId, LeagueId, Qty
FROM         Lineups
WHERE        (PositionId = 1 AND Qty = 1) 
AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Lineups WHERE PositionId=3 AND Qty=2)
```